# My lazy load won't load after scroll, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I followed this from google. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/

The lazy loads won't load. After clicking through the category it won't present the images.

This is the javascript I am using.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy"));

  if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
    let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
      entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          let lazyImage = entry.target;
          lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
          lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
          lazyImage.classList.remove("lazy");
          lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
        }
      });
    });

    lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
      lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
    });
  } else {
    // Possibly fall back to a more compatible method here
  }
});
```

Link to the website. http://highdemanddesigns.com/calhoun/portfolio

Comment: have you checked the **browser developer tools console** for errors?

Comment: Yep, no errors at all. No idea what's the problem.